# Weeding out invalid html code with regex

Tags: html, regex, img

I need a pcre regex that will select all html img tags without a src part. Long story. With help I got to `(?-s)<img(?!.*?src).*?\/>` which worked fine until a line got a second img tag WITH src part. The regex matched the first `<img` with the last `/>` :(

How can I select the bad part `<img border="0" />` from:

```
<p align="center"><img border="0" /> <a href="http://www.megaevent2014.com/enllac/"><img alt src="http://www.megaevent2014.com/banner/gran/" /></a></p>
```

In one regular expression.

And the img tags can be invalid for a lot of reasons. Weeding out "border" does not help. I need to select the tags without src, not caring about anything else.

Please advice,
Best regards, Peter

Comment: See this answer on stackoverflow!! http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags/1732454#1732454

Comment: @LordPeter True, it cannot be performed in a failproof manner. But in certain limited contexts it can work.

Answer (score 0):

The following regex pattern works for me, and should be well-formed for PCRE Regex:

```
<img(\s*(?!src)([\w\-])+=([\"\'])[^\"\']+\3)*\s*\/?>
```

- To break it down, you start with the literal `<img`, and then the `\s*` matches any white space character `[\r\n\t\f ]` zero or unlimited times.
- The `(?!src)` is the negative lookahead, which makes sure that the string `src` is **NOT** matched.
- The second capture group `([\w\-])+` searches for any of `[a-zA-Z0-9_]` between one and unlimited times, and is greedy (find it as many times as possible), and the `\-` is a literal looking for a hyphen in case it exists somewhere within the `<img>` tag pair.
- The `=` is a literal search for an equal sign.
- The third capture group, `([\"\'])[^\"\']+\3` seeks to match either a single or double quote, then anything *BUT* a single or double quote (one or more times), and then the `\3` matches whatever was found as the third capture group (either a single or a double quote.)
- Finally the `\s*` matches any white space character `[\r\n\t\f ]` zero or unlimited times, the `\/?` matches a forward slash exactly one time, and the `>` is the closing bracket of the entire affair.

Regex is fun. :-)